# Promoting a pre-release package to release in Python without rebuilding?

Tags: python, github-actions, pypi, cicd, fleet

I am configuring a CI/CD pipeline using GitHub Actions to build, test, and upload Python packages to an internal PyPI registry. The tools I'm using include pyproject.toml, fleet, pytest, and twine.

In the initial flow, I build the package using a pre-release version, such as 1.0.0-rc4. After building, I upload the package to the registry. During the build process, the Python build system names the artifacts using the package name and version.

Now, in the second flow, my goal is to take the previously built package and repackage it with a stable version. I want to upload this new package as the stable version to the registry. However, I have not found any specific guidance or references on how to achieve this without rebuilding the package from scratch.

The only approach I have come across in the documentation involves modifying the version in the pyproject.toml file and rebuilding the package entirely. Unfortunately, this requires additional time and resources.

I am wondering if there is an alternative solution or workaround available that allows me to repackage the existing package with a stable version and upload it to the registry without having to rebuild it completely. Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated.

I tried reading the documentation but couldn't find any solution.
I expect to find a way to promote/repackage the built package, instead of building it again.

Comment: Could you share your current workflow, and what would be the trigger of the second workflow you plan to build?

Comment: I can. But the point is how to promote it, the github workflow itself is not really important. The real question is if python building tools support such action.

Comment: To understand the concept, see how NuGet describes the concept: 
[NuGet Pre-Release Packages & Repackaging](https://docs.inedo.com/docs/proget-packages-repackaging)